# Finding the error in a double integral of a function in Python

Tags: python, integration, numerical-integration

I have been given a function of the acceleration of an object but am not able to explicitly calculate the integral of this function so have to use numerical approximations.

However since i'm trying to find the distance that the object travels while accelerating then I would need the function of velocity.

Using something like `v[i+1] = a[i](t[i+1] - t[i]) + v[i]` for velocity with small enough intervals of `t` should find a good approximation and then I can use the same trick for distance.

But how would I go about finding the error of this function? Are there better ways of finding the double integral?

Comment: You won't be able to find the distance traveled only given the acceleration over time; the initial velocity is necessary as well.

Comment: Is the acceleration given explicitly or can you only compute it at certain predetermined points in time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable doing a little research I would recommend importing scipy

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Comment: I know how to use this for single integrals or double integrals that contain two variables, but since I am trying to find the distance from acceleration it is just a function of t rather than x and y for example.
If I was to use dblquad then I think all it would do is evaluate the integral to get velocity, then simply integrate that constant rather than the function a second time.

Comment: I have not played around with physics lately, but I found this in the physics section of StackExchange. Hope that you can apply the data you have to this using Scipy. Good luck!
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15620